# Tv cable, safe to cut?

Tags: electrical

I have long ends of to cable coming out of baseboards in several rooms. Is it safe to cut off? Cable is no longer used in the house.

Answer (score 2):

I push the cable back into the wall or floor until just the connector is sticking out.  You may not want cable right now, but never say never - you might want high speed internet or have a tenant or a next homeowner.  I know cable will install it for "free" but it's not really free, it costs you some discounts/rebates for an installer to come.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I'd suggest re-routing them just in case someone does want to use cable/internet later.

And if your going to have the walls open anyway, now is a perfect time to install CAT6a Ethernet cable for your home network!